# Reroute user like Google Map in android application

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a project where I need to `navigate/reroute user` just like Google Map Navigation.

I am successfully able to get different path locations where I am using distance calculation to get upcoming turns and path.

**ISSUE :**

(1) By time I am checking distance diff between current and upcoming two points but with no success to evaluate precise value. 
Need an Algo / Idea to make rerouting precise.

(2) `U-Turn issue`  Some times the u-turn lat/long is far away with actual turn diameter. In these case my calculations gets disrupted.

I just need an idea on how Google maps provides such a precise value.

Any help !@!

Thanks.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am running on the same problem

Comment: As of now we are indulged in some other process of application so have not make a much of it. For a try, please check values in incremental or Decremented order i.e. Evaluate probability that if the value is increasing or decreasing and match it with your own value.